How reliable is GCHeapStats_V1 GCHandleCount?
I have seen GCHandleCount from GCHeapStats_V1 report values 3 orders of magnitude above the counts I get from SOS GCHandles command.
I know that GCHandleCount tracks counts "loosely":

Another thing worth mentioning is we track GCHandleCount “loosely” in coreclr, as in, we don’t use Interlocked inc/dec for perf reasons. We just do ++/– so this count is a rough figure but gives you a good idea perf wise (eg, in the example shown, that’s a lot of handles and definitely worth some investigation).

But 3 orders of magnitude seems too much... How reliable is that value? Should I just ignore it completely? Or is it correct but tracking something different from SOS GCHandles?
